# Apply Css style to all tags inside Div

Tags: css

How to apply style to all specific tags inside a div? I try this:

```
#FirstSection > table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #D3D8D8 !important;
}
```

Comment: `#FirstSection *{...}`

Comment: all tags in the first level or in all levels?

Comment: All tags in all levels inside Div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had to use in your CSS

```
#FirstSection, #FirstSection * {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

Note; The `#FirstSection *` is only for the nested elements. The `*` is a universal selector who fits for everything (the nested depth doesn't matter), but it has to be existant. So for your DIV itself you need `#FirstSection`additionally.
You can see it on this example:

```css
#FirstSection, #FirstSection * {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<div>Normal</div>
<div id="FirstSection">Firstsection
  <p>P-Test  </p>
  <table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
  </table>
  <div>Second
    <span>Nested span</span>
    Div
    <a href='google.com'>google.com</a>
    <div>Third</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>After</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I m near now. But what happens if I just want to add the style in table tags (th,td,etc),  but not to all tags. I think I can resolve that if I put the table inside a DIV, but meabe there is a way with css. Sory for my english and thanks.

Comment: Than use instead of `#FirstSection * ` this `#FirstSection td, #FirstSection th`